# How do I select ip using UIPickerView using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview

I own a vpn app. Our app comes predefined with one server, this server is hard coded into the app. It looks like this; `let serverAddress = "0.0.0.0"` (but with a real server ip).

I have made a picker view using the following:

`let IPs = ["GER1", "UK1", "GER2", "UK2"]`

I now want to know how to say " `GER1=192.168.1.2` `UK1=192.168.1.3` `GER2=192.168.1.4` `UK2=192.168.1.5` "

and then parse it to `let serverAddress = "0.0.0.0"` replacing `0.0.0.0` with the selected ip.

In summary: 
I only have 1 server specified, If I ever wanted to change it I'd change the `let serverAddress = "0.0.0.0"` but I would like to add more servers as an option. so I somehow need to change `0.0.0.0`

I personally think picker view is the best way of doing it. But I am open to ideas.

The source code I am working with is here: https://github.com/lxdcn/NEPacketTunnelVPNDemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should change the `serverAddress` to a `var` instead of a `let`.

Then, you should use the delegate function: `didSelectRow`, to change `serverAddress` to which server address that was selected.

To achieve this, I recommend using a dictionary to store all of your servers to select from like so:

```
class YourViewController {
    // MARK: - Server Address

    var serverAddress = "0.0.0.0"

    // MARK: Picker View Resources

    let serverPicker = UIPickerView() {
        didSet {
            serverPicker.delegate = self
            serverPicker.dataSource = self
        }
    }
    var serverPickerData:[(key: String, value: String)] = [("base", "0.0.0.0"), ("ger1", "192.68.1.2"), ("uk1", "192.68.1.3"), ("ger2", "192.68.1.4"), ("uk2", "192.68.1.5")]


    .... 

}


extension YourViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    // MARK: - UIPicker View Delegate

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return serverPickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        serverAddress = serverPickerData[row].value
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return "\(serverPickerData[row].key) - \(serverPickerData[row].value)"
    }

}
```

Then whenever you need to add a server to the UIPicker, you can simply push a new dictionary value onto your dictionary

Comment: Thank you! I will try this when I am home and hope it works :)

Comment: @MrBenFTW if it works for you, I'd appreciate if you accepted this answer! Good luck

Comment: Hi, I am confused as to where I put this, I have uploaded the whole `viewcontroller.swift` file to paste bin, if you could. Would you copy, add your code and upload back :) Thank you! ( I did try doing it my self but got a bunch of errors) paste bin: https://pastebin.com/dvED3KN7

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect where this code should go. (I also added the `picker.dataSource = self` line).

 My guess is the errors you are getting are because the lines `picker.dataSource = self` and `picker.delegate = self` are invalid because your viewController does not extend the UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource protocols, meaning that when you assign the pickers protocols to `self` the compiler doesn't recognize the ViewController as having those protocol functions.

Comment: Error: Use of undeclared type 'ServerPickerData' another error 'let' declarations cannot be observing properties. Last error: Method 'pickerView(pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:)' has different argument labels from those required by protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource' ('pickerView(_:numberOfRowsInComponent:)')

Comment: I should note that i have removed all code to do with the PickerView when you answered, I am starting fresh. I also removed the picker view on the story board. I will make one now.

Comment: Heads up; I am doing my UI the visual way, not via code

Comment: 1) Change your `let` to a `var` .... 

2) Start typing in `pickerView(...` and the suggestions should have one with ` numberOfComponents` ... etc.

Comment: Your errors are getting off topic of your question. Please go find a tutorial about UIPickerView implementation. I am not a personal debugger

Comment: updated answer again to have a `_` in the first parameter of each protocol function. That could be causing your second issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry for being annoying. I managed to fix all but one error. `Use of undeclared type 'serverPickerData'` I have tried searching to see if it is an obvious fix, but I don't see anywhere where it is being incorrectly called. Please could you help me? Thank you

Comment: what did you name the dictionary that hosts your data?

Comment: whatever you named the dictionary, you need to use that name for accessing the information. Make sure the PickerDelegate extends the same ViewController that has the dictionary

Comment: Dictionary? I'm not sure I have a dictionary.

Comment: `var serverPickerData:[(key: String, value: String)] = [("base", "0.0.0.0"), ("ger1", "192.68.1.2"), ("uk1", "192.68.1.3"), ("ger2", "192.68.1.4"), ("uk2", "192.68.1.5")]` that is a dictionary...

Comment: I have the dictionary right above the `var serverAddress: serverPickerData = .base` https://imgur.com/a/P6tlovP

Comment: That's my bad. I forgot the change that variable back to a string when I removed the answer that included utilizing an `enum`. You're `serverAddress` needs to be the same type as the `value` in your dictionary, in this case it is a string.

Comment: I made it `lazy var serverAddress = serverPickerData = .base ` and now I get this: Type '[(key: String, value: String)]' has no member 'base'; did you mean 'last'?

Comment: No, you need to make it this: `var serverAddress = "0.0.0.0"`. 

The `serverPickerData` is a *dictionary* with a *key* of type string (i.e. the alias of your IP Address) and a *value* of type string (i.e. the IP Address). 

Your variable `serverAddress` is of type string that represents the current IP Address. You need your `serverAddress` to be the same type as the *value* that was selected out of your dictionary via a UIPicker. That type is `string`.

Make your declaration of `serverAddress` this: `var serverAddress = "0.0.0.0"`

Comment: Hi, thank you it finally built! The app terminates with this `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<OneProxy.ViewController 0x107003600> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ServerPickerData.'`

Comment: That's an issue with how you are updating that specific variable, not with how the picker is implemented. I don't know enough about your project to know how you set that variable. You will have to figure that out on your own. (I suggest either assigning it the same place you set the variable `serverAddress` or you could use the `didSet` protocol on a variable to set it there.)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will mark it as solved. Thanks again!